# Show custom length of a string of a paragraph

Tags: javascript, html

I have 3 elements on is input second is button and the third is a paragraph. Suppose paragraph has very long string but we want to display a limited part of that paragraph.

Its working in my code but in case I put a value let's say 100 so it will display me the 100 string of that paragraph but in that case again if I want to display more than 100 strings so it does not work.

Please find the code following-

```
<input type="number" id="strinput" name="">
<button id="btn" onclick="submitformstr()">Submit</button>

<article id="totalchars">
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Esse nihil minima atque veniam repudiandae harum, consectetur voluptas nam amet fugiat eligendi vitae aliquam eum recusandae voluptatum, sapiente autem ratione. Praesentium totam repellat recusandae ad distinctio voluptas, modi expedita similique voluptate, culpa officiis. Assumenda similique, ipsum nostrum suscipit vero a asperiores maiores qui, sint esse nesciunt laborum consequuntur facere! Voluptatem asperiores, fuga maxime cumque dicta numquam tempora perferendis eos, soluta laboriosam, ad minima quisquam excepturi veniam fugit, reiciendis molestiae. Repudiandae unde fugiat, delectus neque, quam eligendi repellat facilis ipsum nulla mollitia, quos incidunt iusto voluptas ad. Quisquam velit excepturi commodi provident.
</article>

<script>
  function submitformstr() {
    const strn = document.getElementById('strinput');
    const strnval = strn.value;
    console.log(strnval);
    const totalchars = document.getElementById('totalchars').innerText;
    const showchars = totalchars.substring(0, strnval);
    document.getElementById('totalchars').innerText = showchars;
  }
</script>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just define `const totalchars = document.getElementById('totalchars').innerText;` this outside the function.

```js
const totalchars = document.getElementById('totalchars').innerText;
function submitformstr() {
    const strn = document.getElementById('strinput');
    const strnval = strn.value;
    console.log(strnval);
   
    const showchars = totalchars.substring(0, strnval);
    document.getElementById('totalchars').innerText = showchars;
}
```

```html
<input type="number" id="strinput" name="">
<button id="btn" onclick="submitformstr()">Submit</button>

<article id="totalchars">
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Esse nihil minima atque veniam repudiandae harum, consectetur voluptas nam amet fugiat eligendi vitae aliquam eum recusandae voluptatum, sapiente autem ratione. Praesentium totam repellat recusandae ad distinctio voluptas, modi expedita similique voluptate, culpa officiis. Assumenda similique, ipsum nostrum suscipit vero a asperiores maiores qui, sint esse nesciunt laborum consequuntur facere! Voluptatem asperiores, fuga maxime cumque dicta numquam tempora perferendis eos, soluta laboriosam, ad minima quisquam excepturi veniam fugit, reiciendis molestiae. Repudiandae unde fugiat, delectus neque, quam eligendi repellat facilis ipsum nulla mollitia, quos incidunt iusto voluptas ad. Quisquam velit excepturi commodi provident.
</article>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, it does work. Can you please explain more about that, I mean if want to keep that variable within my function.

Comment: we keep updating the inner text inside that function. so, if we define the variable inside it will take only the updated value.

Answer (score 2):

This is happening because every time you run the function it overwrites the `innerHTML` so after first call the `innerHTML` contains at most 100 characters. Your `js` function should be like this

```
var innerParagraphText = document.getElementById('totalchars');    
function submitformstr() {
    const strn = document.getElementById('strinput');
    const strnval = strn.value;
    console.log(strnval);
    const totalchars = innerParagraphText.innerText;
    const showchars = totalchars.substring(0, strnval);
    document.getElementById('totalchars').innerText = showchars;
}
```